# Spark-scala: Select distinct arrays from a column dataframe ignoring ordering

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I've been thinking the next problem but I haven't reach the solution: I have a dataframe `df` with only one column `A`, which elements have dataType `Array[String]`. I'm trying to get all the different arrays of `A`, non importing the order of the Strings in the arrays.

For example, if the dataframe is the following:

df.select("A").show()

```
+--------+
|A       |
+--------+
|[a,b,c] |
|[d,e]   |
|[f]     |
|[e,d]   |
|[c,a,b] |
+--------+
```

I would like to get the dataframe

```
+--------+
|[a,b,c] |
|[d,e]   |
|[f]     |
+--------+
```

I've trying make a distinct(), dropDuplicates() and other functions, but It doesnt't work.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` function to collect all the `arrays` in that `column` and then use `udf` function to sort the individual arrays and finally return the `distinct` arrays of the collected list. Finally you can use `explode` function to distribute the distinct collected arrays into separate `rows`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def distinctCollectUDF = udf((a: mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]) => a.map(array => array.sorted).distinct)
df.select(distinctCollectUDF(collect_list("A")).as("A")).withColumn("A", explode($"A")).show(false)
```

You should have your desired result.

Comment: It might be faster to have a udf to sort the array, then call distinct on the dataframe.

Comment: @ayplam may be yes. haven't tested that. But that definitely is another solution

Answer (score 0):

You might try and use the contains method.